# Upgrading Postgres 12 to 13: 'pg_upgrade.exe' fails

Tags: postgresql, windows, upgrade, command-line, postgresql-13

I'm attempting to upgrade a Postgres instance from version 12 to version 13, following the steps outlined at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/pgupgrade.html.

From an elevated command prompt, I'm running (under Windows 10):

> SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin;
>
> pg_upgrade.exe --old-datadir "E:\Programs\PostgreSQL\12\data"
> --new-datadir "E:\Programs\PostgreSQL\13\data" --old-bindir "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin" --new-bindir "C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin" --old-port=5431 --new-port=5432 --jobs=5

The directories appear to be all correct, however the command returns:

> ```
> Performing Consistency Checks  
> -----------------------------  
> Checking cluster versions                                   ok  
>   
> *failure*  
> Consult the last few lines of "pg_upgrade_server_start.log" or "pg_upgrade_server.log" for  
> the probable cause of the failure.  
>   
> connection to database failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)  
>         Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting  
>         TCP/IP connections on port 5431?  
> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)  
>         Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting  
>         TCP/IP connections on port 5431?  
>   
> could not connect to source postmaster started with the command:  
> "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "E:/Programs/PostgreSQL/12/data" -o "-p 5431 -b " start  
> Failure, exiting
> ```

`pg_upgrade_server_start.log` says:

> command: "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "E:/Programs/PostgreSQL/12/data" -o "-p 5431 -b " start >> "pg_upgrade_server_start.log" 2>&1
> The program "postgres" was found by "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_ctl"
> but was not the same version as pg_ctl.
> Check your installation.

I'm at a loss; what might be wrong, and how can I successfully perform this procedure?

Answer (score 1):

The answer had to do with the option "*Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support*" being checked in my locale settings in Windows.

I disabled that option and restarted the computer, the upgrade went without issues after that.

Comment: It seems incredible that there could be a connection (but noting is impossible on Windows). I would have suspected the `PATH` setting: don't set `PATH`, but call `pg_upgrade` with its absolute path.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Indeed. I first suspected locales; then had a hunch, since when installing v12 quite a while back I had to disable that same setting. (Also, I tried not setting `PATH` as well, with the same results).